# a mel delete attributes in maya after import fbx form 3dmax

Tags: maya, mel

20180509

Thanks for your information.
I'd finished mel like that.

```
select -all -hi;
string $allObj[] =`ls -sl -fl `;
for($i=0;$i<`size$allObj`;$i++)
    {
    select -r $allObj[$i];
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "UDP3DSMAX"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "UDP3DSMAX" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "MaxHandle"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "MaxHandle" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "MaxVisibility"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "MaxVisibility" $allObj[$i];
}
    int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "currentUVSet"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "currentUVSet" $allObj[$i];
}
}
```

Show another error
`Cannot delete static attribute 'currentUVSet' from node 'ObjectName'`

Does children of a compound attribute cannot be deleted?

Or is it not nesserary to delete attribute 'currentUVSet'?

---

20180508

After I import fbx file to maya from 3dmax. 
Those objects have some attributes that I don't need.

```
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level"
"UDP3DSMAX"
"MaxHandle"
"currentUVSet"
```

I try to have a mel delete them.

```
string $allObj[] =`ls -sl -fl `;
for($i=0;$i<`size$allObj`;$i++)
    {
    select -r $allObj[$i];
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings";
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent";
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method";
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on";
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length";
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace";
    deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level";
    deleteAttr -at "UDP3DSMAX";
    deleteAttr -at "MaxHandle";
    deleteAttr -at "currentUVSet";
    }
}
```

If I select all objects. mel will show error message like :
`does not have attribute 'UDP3DSMAX'`

Because those objects don't have the same nodes.
How to delete all attributes at correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the complexity a littel bit if you use the catch command:

```
string $attr[] = {"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace"
"mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level"
"UDP3DSMAX"
"MaxHandle"
"currentUVSet"};
string $sel[] = `ls -sl`;
for($i = 0; $i < size($sel); $i++)
{
    for( $k = 0; $k < size($attr); $k++)
    {
        catch(`deleteAttr -at $attr[$k] $sel[$i]`);
    }
}
```

This way you do not have to care about non existing attributes, but of course you do not see other errors that may occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `deleteAttr`, you can check if the attribute exists first:

```
int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node yourObject -exists "yourAttr"`;
if ($attrExists) {
    deleteAttr -at "yourAttr" youObject;
}
```

Comment: In addition it would be a good idea for him to use the FBXASC prefix and delete all of those -- it's FBX's annoying way of copying over new attribute names and it's always going to mark a non-Maya native attribute

Answer (score 0):

Thansks for help

The last mel like that

```
global proc SB_CheckFile()
{
    select -all -hi;
    string $allObj[] =`ls -sl -fl `;
    for($i=0;$i<`size$allObj`;$i++)
    {
        select -r $allObj[$i];
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032useFBXASC032globalFBXASC032settings" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032viewFBXASC032dependent" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032method" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032smoothingFBXASC032on" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032edgeFBXASC032length" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032maxFBXASC032displace" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "mrFBXASC032displacementFBXASC032parametricFBXASC032subdivisionFBXASC032level" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "UDP3DSMAX"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "UDP3DSMAX" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "MaxHandle"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "MaxHandle" $allObj[$i];
        }
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "MaxVisibility"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "MaxVisibility" $allObj[$i];
        }

    }
    select (`ls -type "transform"`);
    string $allObj[] =`ls -sl -fl `;
    for($i=0;$i<`size$allObj`;$i++)
    {
        select -r $allObj[$i];
        int $attrExists = `attributeQuery -node $allObj[$i] -exists "currentUVSet"`;
        if ($attrExists) 
        {
            deleteAttr -at "currentUVSet" $allObj[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do like haggi and use a loop for the attributes instead, so if you ever needed to add/remove attributes then it's very easy to do so.